# How are the convergence conditions/KKT conditions for the soft-margin SVM derived

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, svm, convergence

With reference to CS229 lecture notes [here](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes3.pdf), I do not understand these equations, which apparently signify the convergence conditions/KKT conditions for the SMO algorithm:

[image]

I understand that the Lagrangian would be:[image]

And the dual optimization problem would be:

[image]

And, previously, with hard-margin SVMs, I understand that if $\alpha_{i} \ne 0$, it is a support vector, and only a small number of margins constitute the SV set. But, after the parameter $C$ was introduced, I do not understand how this new condition holds.